# Basic lzw compression help in python

Tags: python, encode, lzw

I'm just trying to write a really basic script that'll take some input text and compress it with lzw, using this package: http://packages.python.org/lzw/

I've never tried any encoding with python before and am thoroughly confused =( - I also can't find any documentation online about it, other than the package info.

Here's what I have:

```
import lzw

file = lzw.readbytes("collectemailinfo.txt", buffersize=1024)
enc = lzw.compress(file)
print enc
```

Any help or pointers of any kind would be much appreciated!

Thanks =)

Comment: Is something wrong with what you have? You probably can't print it and expect it to be human readable, but you can save it somewhere. Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: ah right, thanks - i did try removing the "print enc" and replacing it with "lzw.writebytes(output.txt, enc)" but had no joy with that either =(

Answer (score 12):

Here is the package API: http://packages.python.org/lzw/lzw-module.html

You can read the pseudo code for **compression** and **decompression** [here](http://marknelson.us/1989/10/01/lzw-data-compression/).

Is there anything else you are confused about?

Here is an example:

Python

In this version the dicts contain mixed-typed data:

```
def compress(uncompressed):
    """Compress a string to a list of output symbols."""

    # Build the dictionary.
    dict_size = 256
    dictionary = dict((chr(i), chr(i)) for i in xrange(dict_size))
    # in Python 3: dictionary = {chr(i): chr(i) for i in range(dict_size)}

    w = ""
    result = []
    for c in uncompressed:
        wc = w + c
        if wc in dictionary:
            w = wc
        else:
            result.append(dictionary[w])
            # Add wc to the dictionary.
            dictionary[wc] = dict_size
            dict_size += 1
            w = c

    # Output the code for w.
    if w:
        result.append(dictionary[w])
    return result



def decompress(compressed):
    """Decompress a list of output ks to a string."""

    # Build the dictionary.
    dict_size = 256
    dictionary = dict((chr(i), chr(i)) for i in xrange(dict_size))
    # in Python 3: dictionary = {chr(i): chr(i) for i in range(dict_size)}

    w = result = compressed.pop(0)
    for k in compressed:
        if k in dictionary:
            entry = dictionary[k]
        elif k == dict_size:
            entry = w + w[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError('Bad compressed k: %s' % k)
        result += entry

        # Add w+entry[0] to the dictionary.
        dictionary[dict_size] = w + entry[0]
        dict_size += 1

        w = entry
    return result
```

***How to use:***

```
compressed = compress('TOBEORNOTTOBEORTOBEORNOT')
print (compressed)
decompressed = decompress(compressed)
print (decompressed)
```

***Output***:

```
['T', 'O', 'B', 'E', 'O', 'R', 'N', 'O', 'T', 256, 258, 260, 265, 259, 261, 263]
TOBEORNOTTOBEORTOBEORNOT
```

***NOTE***: this example is taken from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#Python).

Comment: Thanks for the help, yeah I've been been trying to use the info from the package API site, but failing so far =(

With regards to the second link, should I just translate the pseudo code into python and use that?

Comment: I'll have to properly read through it and try to understand what's going on, it's obviously far complicated than I initially thought - i thought a simple 5-6 line script would cover it! I shall have a go now, thanks a lot saher!

Comment: no problem. Glad I could help. I can also help you understand the code if you have some issues with it.